# 4 Neurons to Decide 10 Digits

Tags: algorithms, neural-networks, algorithm-design

I am trying to solve this algorithm exercises (http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#exercise_513527) in Michael Nielson's online book: Neural Networks and Deep Learning (http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#complete_zero).

In another word, he says that there is a way to use four neurons to decide 10 digits on top of of the last hidden layer (which consists of 10 neurons and decides 10 digits separately with a high correct rate).

However I couldn't figure out the way. Do you have any idea about this? I look forward to your idea. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 4 neurons to produce a 4-bit output, which then represents the digit in binary.  A digit in the range 0-9 can be expressed in binary as a 4-bit number.

However, classification accuracy might potentially be worse than the standard method of 10 output neurons with a softmax layer.

Comment: Thank you @D.W.♦ Do you mean that each of the four neurons represents one bit (0 or 1) for each of the four positions? In another word, suppose neuron 1 represents position 1, neuron 2 represents position 2, neuron 3 represents position 3, and neuron 4 represents position 4. Then 0000 detects 0, and 1010 detects 10. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @LinguisticsStudent, yes.